# Eclipse IDE installation Details, org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 is present but not in Run Config, or the Platform Config, or ".product" file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

Unable to include the 64 bit version of SWT jar as it does not show up in any of the list in the ".product" file, the run configuration or the Target platform dialogs.

I have verified that is it installed by looking under the Eclipse IDE installation Details.
Eclipse.org Standard Widget Toolkit for Windows 3.110.0.v20190305-0602  org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64

I expect to see org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64  but only find org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_211
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product x.product -password (omitted)
Command-line arguments:  -product x.product -data C:\Users\ \x-workspace/../runtime-Complete_64BW10.product -dev file:C:/Users/ /x-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/Complete_64BW10.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -password (omitted) -password (omitted)
```

Comment: You have a [similar opened question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56137927/6505250). The target platform is the platform on which your RCP application is based. The Eclipse IDE used to develop this RCP application can be used as a target platform but in most cases you don't do that. If and only if the target platform is the _Running Platform_ you have to reload the target platform after installing plug-ins into the IDE. The mentioned JARs are fragments with filters for specific platform. So make sure the target platform contains all fragments for all targets you want to build.

Comment: What do you have in the Target Platform? It must be something that includes the 64 bit plug-ins.